# How to set a given table cell in Vue.js

Tags: typescript, vue.js, axios, nestjs

I am using @vue/cli 4.1.2 and would like to update given table cells with values from an axios call.
It almost works however instead of putting the result value only into the cell from that row where I pressed the "Run Query" button the entire column "Results" is set to that given result.

Here my code:

```
<template>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="text-center">
        <h1>Recon Query Automator</h1>
       <div v-if="queries.length === 0">
            <h2> No query found at the moment </h2>
        </div>
      </div>

        <div class="">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
              <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col" @click="sort('id')">ID</th>
                  <th scope="col" @click="sort('cat')">Category</th>
                  <th scope="col" @click="sort('name')">Name</th>
                  <th scope="col">SQL</th>
                  <th scope="col">Result</th>
                  <th scope="col">Manage</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr v-for="query in sortedQueries" :key="query._id">
                  <td>{{ query.id }}</td>
                  <td>{{ query.cat }}</td>
                  <td>{{ query.name }}</td>
                  <td>{{ query.sql }}</td>
                  <td v-on:click="runQuery(query.id)">{{ result }}</td>
                  <td>
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                <div class="btn-group" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
                                  <router-link :to="{name: 'Edit', params: {id: query._id}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit Query </router-link>
                                  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" v-on:click="deleteQuery(query._id)">Delete Query</button>
                                  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" v-on:click="runQuery(query.id)">Run Query</button>

                                </div>
                              </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
            <p>
            <button @click="prevPage">Previous</button> 
            <button @click="nextPage">Next</button>
            </p>
          </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

The typescript:

```
<script>
import { server } from "../helper";
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      queries: [],
      result: '',
      currentSort:'name',
      currentSortDir:'asc',
      pageSize:999,
      currentPage:1
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.fetchQueries();
  },
  computed: {
    sortedQueries:function() {
      return this.queries.sort((a,b) => {
        let modifier = 1;
        if(this.currentSortDir === 'desc') modifier = -1;
        if(a[this.currentSort] < b[this.currentSort]) return -1 * modifier;
        if(a[this.currentSort] > b[this.currentSort]) return 1 * modifier;
        return 0;
      }).filter((row, index) => {
        let start = (this.currentPage-1)*this.pageSize;
        let end = this.currentPage*this.pageSize;
        if(index >= start && index < end) return true;
    });;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    fetchQueries() {
      axios
        .get(`${server.baseURL}/reconQuery/queries`)
        .then(data => 
          {
            this.queries = data.data;
          });
    },
    deleteQuery(id) {
      axios
        .delete(`${server.baseURL}/reconQuery/delete?queryID=${id}`)
        .then(data => {
          console.log(data);
          window.location.reload();
        });
    },
    runQuery(id) {
      axios
        .get(`${server.msURL}/run/${id}`)
        .then(Response => {
          alert(Response.data);
          this.result = Response.data;
          console.log(this.result);
        });
        },
    sort(s) {
      //if s == current sort, reverse
      if(s === this.currentSort) {
        this.currentSortDir = this.currentSortDir==='asc'?'desc':'asc';
      }
      this.currentSort = s;
      },
      nextPage() {
        if((this.currentPage*this.pageSize) < this.cats.length) this.currentPage++;
      },
      prevPage() {
        if(this.currentPage > 1) this.currentPage--;
      }
   }
};
</script>
```

I am only interested in the runQuery(id) method as else work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Your result is global for all queries, so it shows for all queries. You need something like:

```
data: () => ({
  result: {}
  ...
}),
methods: {
  runQuery(id) {
    axios
      .get(`${server.msURL}/run/${id}`)
      .then(Response => {
        this.$set(this.result, id, Response.data);
      });
  },
```

and in template:

```
<td v-on:click="runQuery(query.id)">{{ result[query.id] || '' }}</td>
```

Comment: Thank you Darius, however I still do not get a the cell populated:

Comment: I get: result:Object
undefined:11303 in vue-devtools

Comment: It depends on what response you get from `axios.get(`${server.msURL}/run/${id}`)` and what you want to display

Comment: I get this: config: Object { url: "http://localhost:7000/run/35", method: "get", timeout: 0, … }
​
data: 11303 and would like to display "11303" in the cell.